# How can I delete a google cloud project from google cloud console?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google document says "selecting the 'Delete...' option from the project drop-down menu"
https://developers.google.com/console/help/#deletingaproject

But I cannot find this Delete option from the drop-down menu...
[image: My Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

The documenation you are referring to uses this other console https://code.google.com/apis/console/

On the left you will find the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot you have shown is of new UI of console, from that UI you won't be able to delete project.

Sebastian Kreft has given the link click on it that will load old view of console and at left you will see project options to delete.

However this will not physically delete your application you will still have option to un-delete the project.